# Changing return value of Eclipse Extension point implemtation with aspectJ

Tags: eclipse, aspectj, eclipse-pde

I want to modify the internal code of eclipse an extension point implementation. It returns a project where I want to change it to return sub projects of a project. Which we implemented.

Here is it possible to change the return value of a method via aspectJ, so extending the code of eclipse via aspectJ is it possible in practice ? If so, can you give a hint about how to start ?

like

These are the links regarding modifying the return values of a method via aspectj. Can I do this via eclipse ?

like

[Getting a return value or exception from AspectJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656554/getting-a-return-value-or-exception-from-aspectj/22936017#22936017)

[How to modify the attributes of a returned object using AspectJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370167/how-to-modify-the-attributes-of-a-returned-object-using-aspectj)

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I didnt try anything so far, just wonder if it si possible and the right way to do development in eclipse.